# Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected EOF at line 1 column 2 of the JSON5 data. when I npm run build

Tags: npm, json5

When I `npm run build` in my `Vue.js` project, I get bellow error:

```
ERROR in ./src/vendors.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/.babelrc: Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected EOF at line 1 column 2 of the JSON5 data. Still to read: ""
    at error (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:56:25)
    at word (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:393:13)
    at value (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:493:56)
    at Object.parse (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:508:18)
    at ConfigChainBuilder.addConfig (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/build-config-chain.js:150:65)
    at ConfigChainBuilder.findConfigs (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/build-config-chain.js:96:16)
    at buildConfigChain (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/build-config-chain.js:61:13)
    at OptionManager.init (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:354:58)
    at File.initOptions (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
    at new File (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transpile (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:46:20)
    at Object.module.exports (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:163:20)

ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/.babelrc: Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected EOF at line 1 column 2 of the JSON5 data. Still to read: ""
    at error (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:56:25)
    at word (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:393:13)
    at value (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:493:56)
    at Object.parse (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:508:18)
    at ConfigChainBuilder.addConfig (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/build-config-chain.js:150:65)
    at ConfigChainBuilder.findConfigs (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/build-config-chain.js:96:16)
    at buildConfigChain (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/build-config-chain.js:61:13)
    at OptionManager.init (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:354:58)
    at File.initOptions (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
    at new File (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transpile (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:46:20)
    at Object.module.exports (/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:163:20)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! iview-admin@1.1.4 build: `webpack --progress --hide-modules --config build/webpack.prod.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the iview-admin@1.1.4 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ldl/.npm/_logs/2018-05-10T23_56_56_191Z-debug.log
```

How to solve this issue?

I find the `.babelrc` file in my project.

```
/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/.babelrc
/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/estraverse/.babelrc
/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/esrecurse/.babelrc
/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/localforage/.babelrc
/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/escope/.babelrc
/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/postcss-discard-overridden/.babelrc
/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/iview-area/.babelrc
/home/ldl/repo/vue_admin_site/node_modules/mavon-editor/.babelrc
```

Answer (score 1):

You .babelrc file seems to be saved in some other encoding than 'UTF8'. You can change the encoding of your file using notepad++ or download any existing [.babelrc](http://surajitsarkar.co.nf/files/.babelrc) file from any project and change according to your need.

Comment: what if it islinux